# NixOS error: psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, configuration, nixos

I am attempting to use postgresql on NixOS, and face the following error when running `$ psql -U postgres`

```
$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I get a similar error when simply running `$ psql`, using the default user (my username). It appears that my postgres installation does not have a role that I can use to create other roles or run any commands.

**How can I create a role for my postgres user so that I can issue commands?**

I have installed postgres with `$ nix-env -i postgres` and configured in accordance with the [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#module-postgresql), adding

```
services.postgresql.enable = true;
services.postgresql.package = pkgs.postgresql94;
```

to my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` configuration file.

I have also added postgres authentication as suggested in this [example configuration](https://github.com/cstrahan/nixos-config/blob/master/configuration.nix), so the postgresql lines of my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file look like

```
  # postgres
  services.postgresql.enable = true;
  services.postgresql.package = pkgs.postgresql94;
  services.postgresql.authentication = lib.mkForce ''
    # Generated file; do not edit!
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
    local   all             all                                     trust
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
    '';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NixOS when the database *cluster* is initialized (using postgres' initdb) the database super user is set to *root* rather that the default  *postgres*. So `psql -U root` should do the trick.

Comment: I also recommend reading postgresql section in NixOS manual https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#module-postgresql

Comment: Note, that this no longer happens on systems with stateVersion >= 17.09, where `postgres` is now default superuser.